# Should I be adding .pub/bin dir into .gitignore

Tags: dart, gitignore, dart-pub

When creating a Dart library and running my tests, I noticed there's a `.pub` dir with a `.pub/bin/test` subdir in it. Should I be adding `.pub` dir into .gitignore? It doesn't look like something that needs to be in the repo, but I'd like to double check, thus the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole `.pub` directory should be added to `.gitignore`